# Как можно передать параметр, состоящий из нескольких значений, используя Android Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit

Как можно передать список параметров на сервер.
Например список идентификаторов товаров?

```
@GET("basket")
    Call<PriciesInProduct> getPrice(@Query("localityId") int localityId, //список)
```

Это хочу сделать, для того чтобы не запрашивать данные каждого товара по одному, а получить разом

В голову приходит только предварительно сложить в строку и уже строку передать, но думаю это неправильный способ

Comment: Вот тут возможные варианты разбирают: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590454/add-an-array-as-request-parameter-with-retrofit-2

Comment: а как разобрать одинаковый параметр на стороне сервера? До этого использовал
$parameters = $request->getQueryParam('parameters');

Comment: От сервера зависит. Задайте новый вопрос с соответствующими метками.